# font awesome issue placing text under icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to split my html page into two even divs and then put a large font awesome icon in both. 
I've been able to do that. So far so good...

```
<div id='tradingOutageBtnWrapper'>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="addTradingOutageBtnWrap">
        <a id="addTradingOutageBtn" href="addTradingOutage.action">     
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-5x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>
        </a>                    
    </div>

    <div id="viewTradingOutageBtnWrap">
        <a id="viewTradingOutageBtn" href="viewTradingOutage">      
            <i class="fa fa-binoculars fa-5x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>
        </a>        
    </div>  
</div>
```

[image]

The problem I have is that when I add some text under the font awesome icons the text does not center under my font awesome icons as I would expect.

```
<div id='tradingOutageBtnWrapper'>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="addTradingOutageBtnWrap">
        <a id="addTradingOutageBtn" href="addTradingOutage.action">     
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-5x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>
            Add 
        </a>                    
    </div>

    <div id="viewTradingOutageBtnWrap">
        <a id="viewTradingOutageBtn" href="viewTradingOutage">      
            <i class="fa fa-binoculars fa-5x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>
            View
        </a>        
    </div>  
</div>
```

[image]
Where my css is as follows...

```
#tradingOutageBtnWrapper{
    text-align: center;
    height: 600px;
}
#addTradingOutageBtnWrap {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; 
}    
#addTradingOutageBtn {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

Can someone please help me with what I would have to do to center the text under my icons.

thanks

Comment: can you create jsfillde? i think i can solve this in jiffy

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this. I'm not sure why you had different styles for the two `<a>`s, so I had to remove those (they didn't match up with your original screenshots anyway). Also, I didn't feel like including the actual FontAwsome in this post, so I faked it a bit.
Anyway, you get the idea; `inline-block` for the `<div>`s and the `<a>`s, `block` for the `<i>`s.

```css
.fa.fa-plus-circle::before {
  content: '⊕';
}
.fa.fa-binoculars::before {
  content: '⛘';
}
.fa.fa-5x {
  font-size: 5em;
}
.fa.fa-border {
  border: .1em solid;
  border-radius: .1em
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
a i.fa {
  display: block;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="addTradingOutageBtnWrap">
  <a id="addTradingOutageBtn" href="addTradingOutage.action">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-5x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>
    Add
  </a>
</div>

<div id="viewTradingOutageBtnWrap">
  <a id="viewTradingOutageBtn" href="viewTradingOutage">
    <i class="fa fa-binoculars fa-5x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>
    View
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```